# Keyboard won't light up on a Sony Vaio VPCF121FX

Tags: keyboard-backlight

I've been using my Vaio VPCF121FX for over a year now, running Ubuntu 10.10 and then 11.04 and my backlight keyboard has always worked flawlessly. Until now, I just install Ubuntu 11.10 and this feature seems to be missing or forgotten by the developers.

Truth be told, I'm a late-at-night kinda typer so this is something I do use a lot in my day-to-day (or should I say nigth-to-night) laptop environment.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I summed up the suggestions for 12.04 here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/171384/keyboard-backlighting-not-working-on-a-vaio-laptop/171401#171401

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until a fix is released, enter this in a terminal:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight
```

Comment: and how to turn it off back???

Comment: `echo 0` instead of `echo 1`, I would suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Developing on **EboMike**'s answer: you might want to update `/etc/rc.local`, adding the line

`echo 1 | tee /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight`

just before `exit 0` line. This way it is automatically executed when one reboots.