# Cant disable, control keyboard backlight on sony vaio vpcf236fm

Tags: 12.04

Hello i have a sony vaio vpcf236fm. I am unable to disable or control my keyboard backlight. i want to be able to disable it when im running on the battery. Please if i could get help with this id be in your debt.

Comment: Run this command and tell us if it turns it off: `sudo su -c "echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight"`. You will have to type in your password to try it. To open up a terminal, just type Ctrl-Alt-T or open it from the Unity menu.

Comment: @Kupiakos you should add that as an answer!

Comment: Done. I also added a nifty automation script in case the code does actually work.

Comment: Since you said you are unable to disable it or turn it off does this mean that you cannot turn it on or off in VAIO control center or is is not working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run this command and tell us if it turns it off:

```
$ sudo su -c "echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight"
```

You will have to type in your password to try it. To open up a terminal, just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> or open it from the Unity menu.

I'm just going to go ahead and assume this command works and show a nice little script that will automagically turn the keyboard backlight on and off when you unplug the battery. If the command doesn't work....well the script'll be here for future reference then.

Run the command `gksudo gedit '/etc/pm/power.d/99_kbd_backlight'`. Type in your password.

Then paste the following into the `gedit` window:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0
if on_ac_power; then
    echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight
else

    echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight
fi

exit 0
```

Then run this command:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/power.d/99_kbd_backlight
```

You may need to restart your computer for this to take effect. Theoretically, this should turn your keyboard backlight on and off when you plug and unplug your charger.

Edited the script from this source: http://www.techytalk.info/ubuntu-disable-enable-compiz-battery-ac-script/

EDIT: This may be a more "proper" answer:
[Keyboard backlighting not working on a Vaio VPCSB11FX](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171384/keyboard-backlighting-not-working-on-a-vaio-laptop?rq=1)

Comment: The command sudo su -c "echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight" works perfectly wich is awesome but your script doesnt seem to work after i do what you tell me here it gives me an output of.   (gedit:2626): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to parse /usr/share/themes/Mac-X-Lion/gtk-3.0/settings.ini: Key file contains line '/* ' which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment

Comment: ok i figured it out. not only your script works but it also makes the sensor work!!!! im completely amazed. Your awesome thanks so much  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I do a different way, with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight"
MODE=$1
if [ -z $MODE ]
then
    notify-send -t 8000 "No option specified, no operation done"
    exit
fi
if [ ! -w "$FILE" ]
then
    gksudo chmod a+w /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight
fi

if [ "$MODE" = "on" ]
then
    echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight
    notify-send -t 8000 "Keyboard light turned on"
else
    echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight
    notify-send -t 8000 "Keyboard light turned off"
fi
```

Then i map the key with this line in my bashrc

```
 bind '"^[[19;5~": "/home/$(whoami)/bin/keyboard_backlight.sh off\n"'
 bind '"^[[20;5~": "/home/$(whoami)/bin/keyboard_backlight.sh on\n"'
```