# How to turn backlight off | Sony vaio | Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: vaio, keyboard-backlight

How to turn the keyboard back-light off for sony-vaio laptop.
I have tried most of the methods described on the forum but to no avail.

My laptop is sony-vaio SVE15117FNB.
And I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Trusty.

Comment: The commands are `xset led 3` to turn the backlight on and `xset -led 3` to turn the backlight off.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and try this:

> xset led off

If that doesn't work get [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vaio-control-ce/?source=navbar).

References:

[Question from the past.](https://ubuntu4questions.wordpress.com/2015/01/29/turn-off-keyboard-back-light-sony-vaio-svf1521dcxw/)

[Sony Support Answer](https://us.en.kb.sony.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/32161/c/65,66/kw/how%20to%20turn%20off%20keyboard%20backlight/session/L3RpbWUvMTM3ODM4OTgxMC9zaWQvaUF4ZGd6emw%3D)

Comment: Doesn't works :(

Comment: Hm.. Check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/276983/cant-disable-control-keyboard-backlight-on-sony-vaio-vpcf236fm