# Disable keyboard backlight on Sony Vaio S series (2012) (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: keyboard, vaio, sony, backlight

Basically I'd like to disable the keyboard backlight which at the moment is always on, on my Sony Vaio S15 (2012 series).

I've read a few responses in the past which want me to look for the following file: `/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight`, however in my case this file just doesn't exist. Please tell me how do I go about it.

Thanks a ton in advance!

EDIT: I found a site listing the solution although I don't really understand what to do (Being a linux newbie :c ) 
http://oldpapyrus.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/disable-keyboard-backlight-on-vaio-svs13112enb/

EDIT2: **Just tried the above solution, though it doesn't seem to work. PLEASE HELP!**

BUMP. Please reply guys. It has already been a week now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution in [Keyboard backlighting not working on a Vaio VPCSB11FX](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171384/keyboard-backlighting-not-working-on-a-vaio-laptop?rq=1) seems to work for me. To disable:

```
sudo rmmod -v sony-laptop; sudo modprobe -v sony-laptop kbd_backlight=0
```

Permanent solution:

```
echo "options sony-laptop kbd_backlight=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/sony-laptop.conf
```

I was able to make it work in an appropriate way using:

```
sudo rmmod -v sony-laptop; sudo modprobe -v sony-laptop kbd_backlight=1 kbd_backlight_timeout=1
```

Or permanently:

```
echo "options sony-laptop kbd_backlight=1 kbd_backlight_timeout=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/sony-laptop.conf
```

Comment: I wanted to "keep the sony vaio keyboard backligh always on/enabled" `modinfo sony-laptop` also kbd_backlight=2 should keep it on but seems to not work, so I am using your answer with timeout =3 that seems to keep for a long time (doesnt mean 3s) and will suffice thx!