# What values can kbd_backlight files take?

Tags: keyboard, brightness, backlight, vaio, sony

[I wish to turn off my keyboard backlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987711/how-do-i-turn-off-the-backlight-on-my-keyboard-2011-sony-vaio-pcg-41217n-lapto), and I have discovered the files `kbd_backlight` and `kbd_backlight_timeout` in `/sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop`. Both say '-1' when opened in gedit. What values can I change these text files to, what do these values mean, and where do you go to learn such information?

A comment below indicates [values for these files are listed in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/171401/760090).

Comment: "parm:           kbd_backlight_timeout:set this to 0 to set the default 10 seconds timeout, 1 for 30 seconds, 2 for 60 seconds and 3 to disable timeout (default: 0) (int)"

Comment: Why is the value at -1? What does -1 mean? The question is not a duplicate of that question because I am asking about those files and where their meaning is documented, not asking how to get the backlight working. How do I change the values to 0? I am not able to save changes from gedit because the files are read-only.

Comment: That command is probably all documentation there is; it gets the docs from the module: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.8/source/drivers/platform/x86/sony-laptop.c#L139. If `-1` is not given in it, then you'll have to read the code to see what happens when it's -1.

Comment: Why did you post this explanation about those files' values as a comment instead of as an answer? Is it not appropriate to accept what you've said as an answer (if it were posted as an answer)?

Comment: Because I don't see much value in repeating half of what an another comprehensive answer already says.