# Lubuntu - Turn on keybaord backlight - Sony Vaio Laptop

Tags: lubuntu, backlight, vaio

I have installed Lubuntu on my Sony Vaio and my keybaord backlight isn't working. I have tried a few things in command line but they don't appear to have worked.

I know that the backlight is still working because when the computer first turns on the backlight is on for around 30 seconds but then it switches off.

Comment: Let us know the things you've tried. Have you looked into  /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop?

Comment: Sometimes you can install `lm-sensors` and then run `sudo sensors-detect` and follow the instructions. Some people have reported the backlights working after performing this procedure. Also, see this other related post and please tell us if any of these solutions have worked for you. Thanks! https://askubuntu.com/questions/171384/keyboard-backlighting-not-working-on-a-vaio-vpcsb11fx

Comment: also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/68423/keyboard-wont-light-up-on-a-sony-vaio-vpcf121fx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You haven't told us your release of Lubuntu  (as I have Lubuntu on my vaio and I could look); the keyboard backlight worked for 18.10, 19.04 and I could look for you; alas I don't know if you're using older LXDE or modern LXQt).  My keyboard light goes off too after a time, but turns back on whenever I hit a key. Does this happen when you use the keyboard? or is it only on for 30 seconds after boot (then remains off)?

Comment: echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/sony- 
    laptop/kbd_backlight
    tee: /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/kbd_backlight: 
    Permission denied
    1

Comment: It is list as a sensor and running the code on https://askubuntu.com/questions/171384/keyboard-backlighting-not-working-on-a-vaio-vpcsb11fx doesn't work.

Comment: I have found the kbd_backlight files in /sys/module/sony_laptop/parameters

I changed the ownership from root to my user in terminal and changed the values from -1 in both kbd_backlight and kbd_backlight_timeout to 1 and 2. My keyboard didn't light up and upon a restart the values changed back to -1 and root now ownes the files.

Comment: I am using LXQT 0.14.1 and lubuntu 19.04 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on my VAIO, you need to add a sony-laptop.conf file and an option to enable/disable the backlighting:

```
$ echo "options sony-laptop kbd_backlight=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/sony-laptop.conf
```

Then reboot and the backlight should be enabled.

I found the answer after much searching on medium.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and would appreciate some assistance.

Comment: What can I help you with? Have you added the above mentioned line to sony-laptop.conf ?

Comment: yes, I did. It hasn't helped.